# Problem with sentences structures

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I have problem with sentences structures.

I have sentences:

> 1. He possesses wide span of skills and specialized knowledge in
>      design, implementation, management, and maintenance a fully
>      redundant high available **fault tolerant wired and wireless
>      production network** architecture.
> 2. He possesses wide span of skills and specialized knowledge in
>      design, implementation, management, and maintenance a fully
>      redundant high available **fault tolerant production wired and
>      wireless network** architecture.

I am not sure, which sentence is grammatically correct?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: "*a* wide span of skills"  and  "... , and maintenance *of* fully redundant fault-tolerant wired and wireless networks".  I am not sure what "production" does for your sentence.  Is there such a thing as a non-production network? Or does that simply mean real-world with users, not testing?

Comment: If something like this helps, feel free to use it: "Widely skilled in design, implementation, management and maintenance, he possesses specialized knowledge of the architecture of fully redundant, highly available, fault-tolerant production networks, of both the wired and wireless types."  Too many matters of translation are there to detail in a comment, and of course one can word the sentence other ways to emphasize other points, but I will note one item: the hyphen. The English construct "adverb adjective noun" is usually styled "adverb-adjective noun" if the adverb does not end in *-ly.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few mistakes in each, but easily fixable. Using your words, it should be written  "He possesses a wide array of skills and specialized knowledge in the design, implementation, management(,) and maintenance of fully redundant (high available? might want to check that) fault-tolerant wired and wireless (production) network architecture."

Edit: If you wish you use "spans," it is probably better to say "His skill set spans (subject list)" but there is always a chance it could even come off a little strange.